# HEREMaps react cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, maps, typeerror

Currently trying to use `react-here-maps` but I have no luck using it.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import HEREMap from 'react-here-maps';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export default class Map extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <HEREMap
                appId="KEY"
                appCode="KEY"
                center={{ lat: 0, lng: 0 }}
                zoom={14}
            />
        )
    }
}
```

When using this component in my app it gives the error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'object' of undefined
```

The first detailed error lines are this

```
     55 | }
  56 | // define the context types that are passed down from a <HEREMap> instance
  57 | Circle.contextTypes = {
> 58 |     map: React.PropTypes.object
  59 | };
  60 | Circle.defaultProps = {
  61 |     fillColor: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)",
```

I think it has something to do with proptypes but I have that installed already. Anyone knows how to fix this?